# Rotation of bodies about centre of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Imagine two masses connected by a massless, inextensible string kept on a smooth, horizontal plane. Now suppose one of the masses is given a velocity perpendicular to the string. So the masses will rotate about their centre of mass, which lies on the string. My question, how can we determine the velocity of the other block during motion of system?

Consequently, how to find the tension present in the string during the motion of the bodies?

Comment: You know $v = \omega r$ where $r$ is distance from rotation center and $\omega$ is the rotational speed (in radians per second).

Comment: Might as well call it a rigid rod, since the masses will never approach each other.  Anyway, since the string/rod is responsible for transferring angular momentum to the second mass, I suspect the solution may be periodic in nature.

Answer (score 2):

Mass 1 is given an initial velocity $v_1(0)=v_o$. You want the velocity $v_2(t)$ of mass 2.

One way to do this is to break up the motion of mass 2 into the motion of the center of mass of the two-mass system, and the motion of mass 2 relative to the center of mass: 
$$\vec{v}_2(t)=\vec{v}_2^\text{(lab)}(t)=\vec{v}_\text{cm}^\text{(lab)}(t)+\vec{v}_2^\text{(cm)}(t).$$

- The center of mass velocity at time zero, $\vec{v}_\text{cm}^\text{(lab)}(0),$ can be found from your initial conditions. If you want $\vec{v}_\text{cm}^\text{(lab)}(t)$, use conservation of momentum of the system.
- The velocity of mass 2 *about the center of mass* can be found by going into the center of mass frame and realizing that you have simple circular motion.

The tension $T$ in the string can be found by again going into the center of mass frame and utilizing uniform circular motion.

Comment: I have a follow-up question; why masses will rotate around their centre of mass?

Comment: Good question. You might want to ask this as a separate question.